# organizing strings using a hash table C++

Tags: c++, string, hash

I'm writing a code that:

- asks for a string
- converts that string into it's ascii value
- then send this number to folding function that only take the first 8 digits 
  from the right , split it into 3 numbers , add them together ,then take the first 3 digits from the right as well
- this number with 3 digits is the order of the the string in an array of     pointers that represent the hash table

For example: If I input the string "abclmn" -> 979899100108109110 -> folding function 08109110 split the number into 3 numbers like so -> 081,091,10 -> 81+91+10=182
   and 182 is where the string "abclmn" should be inserted in the hash table

---

This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<string>
#include<queue>
using namespace std;
int folding(long int num1)
{
    int num;
    num=num1%100000000;
    int x=num/100000;
    int y=(num%100000)/100;
    int z=num%100;
    int w=(x+y+z)%1000;

    return w;
}

int main()
{    
    string s;
    cout<<"input the variable name"<<endl;
    cin>>s;

    int* a=new int [s.length()];
    for (int i=0;i<(s.length());++i)
    {
        a[i]=(int)s[i];
    }

    queue<int> q;

    for (int i=0;i<(s.length());++i)
    {
        if (a[i]<10) q.push(a[i]);
        else 
        if ((a[i]>9)&&(a[i]<100))
        {
            q.push(a[i]/10);
            q.push(a[i]%10);    
        }
        else if (a[i]>100)
        {
            q.push(a[i]/100);
            q.push((a[i]%100)/10);
            q.push(a[i]%10);

        }
    }//filling the number in a queue

    long int num=0;
    for (int i=(q.size());i>0;--i)
    {
        num=num+(q.front()*pow(10*1.0,i-1));
        q.pop();
    }

    cout<<"the answer"<<folding(num)<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

---

My problem is that I don't know how long the string will be
so if the string is too along the output is going to be a random value
and that's because I'm using long int for the output value and it's not enough.

So is there a solution for this or another way to get the same result?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why do you need to convert all the string to ascii value if you are using only the 8 last digits ?

Comment: Do you need to use exactly the folding function described or can you choose another one? Taking just the sum (mod 256) of the ascii values would be much easier and give essentially the same result

Comment: It's a project I'm working on and we have to use this function

Comment: *"My problem is that I don't know how long the string is gonna be"* - why care? Your stated "folding function" will only use the last 8 characters anyway, so you can encode ASCII values from the right of the string and stop once you have a > 8 character sequence to fold. At most, you'll be passing in 99999999 which you've said you'll split into 99, 999 and 999 and add: that won't overflow an `int`.  (Very poor hash function BTW).

Comment: Good point thanks
I know it's a really really poor hash function,but still that what the project is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> convert that string into it's ascii value
>
> then send this number to
>   folding function that only take the first 8 digits from the right ,
>   split it into 3 numbers , add them together ,then take the first 3
>   digits from the right as well

Well, since you're only interested in the last 8 digits, we don't need to convert the entire string to its ASCII representation.
Let's try traversing backwards along the string and building our number that way.

```
int getDigits( std::string s ) {
    long long int digits = 0;
    int runningLength = 0;
    int prevLength = 0;
    for ( auto it = s.rbegin(); it != s.rend(); ++it ) {
        runningLength += prevLength;
        //if digits is a 7 digit number then appending a 3 digit number would overflow an int
        digits += (long long int)*it * pow(10, runningLength);
        //we have to work out the length of the current digit
        //so we know how much we need to shift by next time
        int dLength = 0;
        for ( int d = *it; d > 0; dLength++, d /= 10 );
        prevLength = dLength;
        if ( digits >= 100000000 ) break;
    }
    return digits % 100000000;
}
```

> then send this number to folding function that only take the first 8
>   digits from the right , split it into 3 numbers , add them together
>   ,then take the first 3 digits from the right as well

Your code looks fine for that.

The code to split the string into digits would be a lot neater if you worked in base 16 (and assumed printable ASCII only).